# Web page navigation reverting back to page 1

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I am pulling some data of yellowpages, which is pulling off fine. However my issue is around the page navigation. Although It navigates fine from page 1 to 2 when it trys to navigate to page 3 my code goes back to page 1 and extracts the data again. The data extraction is fine the issue is the navigation.

[YellowPage.ca](https://www.yellowpages.ca)

This is what I have identified and I think is the issue, but do not know how to resolve it.

[image: page1]

When the page navigates to page 2, the class for the 'emptyPageButton' changes to the same class to navigate to the NEXT PAGE, so instead of going forward to the next page, which would be page 3, it goes back to page 1. If I stated that 10 pages should be extracted it will extract each page 1 + 2 five times each as it will keep going back and forth between the two pages.

[image: Page 2]

I have made several attempts, but they do not work. I can get as far as page2 and then it goes back to page 1

**WITH CLASS** works up to page 2 then goes back to page 1

```
''' Searches Number of Pages entered in Sheet20 rage J9

    If pageNumber >= Replace(Worksheets("Sheet20").Range("J9").Value, "", "+") Then Exit Do
       Set nextPageElement = HTML.getElementsByClassName("ypbtn btn-theme pageButton ")(0)
       'Set nextPageElement = HTML.getElementsByClassName("ypbtn btn-theme pageButton ")(1)
       'Set nextPageElement = HTML.getElementsByClassName("ypbtn btn-theme pageButton ")(0).children (0)
       'Set nextPageElement = HTML.getElementsByClassName("ypbtn btn-theme pageButton ")(1).children (0)
       'Set nextPageElement = HTML.getElementsByClassName("ypbtn btn-theme pageButton ")(1).children (1)
       'Set nextPageElement = HTML.getElementsByClassName("view_more_section_noScroll ")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(1)
          If nextPageElement Is Nothing Then Exit Do
             nextPageElement.Click 'next web page
             Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
```

**WITH QUERY SELECTOR** works up to page 2 then goes back to page 1

```
''' Searches Number of Pages entered in Sheet20 rage J9

    If pageNumber >= Replace(Worksheets("Sheet20").Range("J9").Value, "", "+") Then Exit Do
       Set nextPageElement = HTML.querySelector(".view_more_section_noScroll .pageButton")
          If Not nextPageElement Is Nothing Then
             nextPageElement.Click
             Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
          Else:
             Exit Do
         End If
```

**Snippet for page1**

```html
<div class="view_more_section_noScroll">
  <div class="emptyPageButton"></div>
  <span class="pageCount">
<span class="bold">
1 /
</span>
  <span class="">
37</span>
  </span>
  <a href="/search/si/2/car+dealership/Toronto+ON" data-analytics="{&quot;event_name&quot;:&quot;click - load_more - Serp &quot;,&quot;lk_se_id&quot;:&quot;f32f0ee7-8492-46dd-87da-7b621c162879_Y2FyIGRlYWxlcnNoaXA_VG9yb250byBPTg&quot;,&quot;lk_name&quot;:&quot;next_serp&quot;}"
    class="ypbtn btn-theme pageButton">Next
&gt;&gt;</a>
</div>
```

**Snippet for page2 and beyond**

```html
<div class="view_more_section_noScroll">
  <a href="/search/si/1/car+dealership/Toronto+ON" data-analytics="{&quot;event_name&quot;:&quot;click - previous_page - Serp &quot;,&quot;lk_se_id&quot;:&quot;f32f0ee7-8492-46dd-87da-7b621c162879_Y2FyIGRlYWxlcnNoaXA_VG9yb250byBPTg&quot;,&quot;lk_name&quot;:&quot;previous_serp&quot;}"
    class="ypbtn btn-theme pageButton">&lt;&lt; Previous</a>
  <span class="pageCount">
<span class="bold">
2 /
</span>
  <span class="">
37</span>
  </span>
  <a href="/search/si/3/car+dealership/Toronto+ON" data-analytics="{&quot;event_name&quot;:&quot;click - load_more - Serp &quot;,&quot;lk_se_id&quot;:&quot;f32f0ee7-8492-46dd-87da-7b621c162879_Y2FyIGRlYWxlcnNoaXA_VG9yb250byBPTg&quot;,&quot;lk_name&quot;:&quot;next_serp&quot;}"
    class="ypbtn btn-theme pageButton">Next
&gt;&gt;</a>
</div>
```

QUESTION, Can someone advise what the correct class or querySelector is for the navigation?

Results
[image: results]

As aways thanks in advance.

'''##########################   UPDATED THUR 8/4/2021 #####################

The full code is large, I have reduced the code a lot to make it much easier to read as the ONLY ISSUE is the page navigation. This code should give you and idea of what i am trying to do. Currently it overides previous extracted results, I have deleted something in the code by error, please ignore this for now as ONLY THE PAGE NAVIGATION IS AN ISSUE

```
Private Sub YellowPagesCa()

Dim HTML As htmlDocument
Dim objIE As Object
Dim result As String 'string variable that will hold our result link
Dim pageNumber As Long ' page no.
Dim nextPageElement As Object 'page element
Dim HtmlText As Variant ' for html data
Dim wsSheet As Worksheet ' WorkSheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sht As Worksheet

        Set wb = ThisWorkbook
            Set wsSheet = wb.Sheets("YellowPages")
             Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("YellowPages")
              
'+++++ Internet Explorer ++++++
        Set objIE = New InternetExplorer 'initiating a new instance of Internet Explorer and asigning it to objIE
        objIE.Visible = True
            objIE.navigate "https://www.yellowpages.ca/search/si/1/car+dealer/Toronto+ON"
            
        Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop 'wait here a few seconds while the browser is busy
        
        Set HTML = objIE.document
        Set elements = HTML.getElementsByClassName("listing_right_section")

    For Each element In elements
            DoEvents
''' Element 1
        If element.getElementsByClassName("listing__name--link listing__link jsListingName")(0) Is Nothing Then
            wsSheet.Cells(sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "A").Value = "-"
        Else
            HtmlText = element.getElementsByClassName("listing__name--link listing__link jsListingName")(0).href
            wsSheet.Cells(sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "A").Value = HtmlText
        End If
         
    'End If
Next element

    Do

'''###############      PAGE NAVIGATION    ##############

    'Searches Number of Pages entered in
    If pageNumber >= 5 Then Exit Do 'Replace(Worksheets("Sheet20").Range("J9").Value, "", "+") Then Exit Do

    Set nextPageElement = HTML.querySelector(".view_more_section_noScroll .pageButton")
   ' Set nextPageElement = HTML.getElementsByClassName("ypbtn btn-theme pageButton ")(0)
        If Not nextPageElement Is Nothing Then
           nextPageElement.Click
            Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
        Else:
            Exit Do
        End If

    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
    Loop
        Set HTML = objIE.document
        pageNumber = pageNumber + 1
  Loop
                
        objIE.Quit ' end and clear browser
            Set objIE = Nothing
            Set HTML = Nothing
            Set nextPageElement = Nothing
            Set HtmlText = Nothing
            Set element = Nothing
        Complete.show
   'End If
  
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to QHarr answer I was able to fix the issue by using parts of it. I have used my Class and QuerySelector code with parts of QHarr QuerySelector answer. I can now navigate the pages fine.

```
Do
' Searches Number of Pages entered in Sheet20 J9
    If pageNumber >= Replace(Worksheets("Sheet20").Range("J9").Value, "", "+") Then Exit Do
        'Set nextPageElement = HTML.querySelector(".view_more_section_noScroll .pageButton")
        Set nextPageElement = HTML.getElementsByClassName("ypbtn btn-theme pageButton")(0) '' using class and NOT QuerySelector here
        If Not nextPageElement Is Nothing Then
         nextPageElement.document.querySelector(".pageCount + a").Click ''NEW PART
            Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
        Else:
            Exit Do
        End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You could loop while

```
ie.document.querySelectorAll(".pageCount + a").Length <> 0
```

and

click the `next` button inside that loop with:

```
ie.document.querySelector(".pageCount + a").click
```

or

```
ie.Navigate2 ie.document.querySelector(".pageCount + a").href
```

This will terminate when there is no more `next` button.

---

Alternatively, extract the page count from the first page and loop to that number of pages, substituting the current page number into the url (e.g. replacing 1 with 2 to get page 2)

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub PrintSomeInfo()

    Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer, re As Object

    Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    
    With re
        .Global = False
        .MultiLine = False
        .Pattern = "(si\/)(\d+)(\/)"
    End With
    
    With ie
    
        .Visible = True
        
        .Navigate2 "https://www.yellowpages.ca/search/si/1/car+dealership/Toronto+ON"
        
        While .Busy Or .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend
        
        Dim pageCount As Long, i As Long
        
        pageCount = CLng(.document.querySelector(".pageCount .bold + span").innerText)
        
        'already on page one so just loop from 2 to pageCount
        For i = 2 To pageCount
             
            .Navigate2 re.Replace(.document.url, "$1" & CStr(i) & "$3")
            
            While .Busy Or .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend
            
            'do something with new page
        Next
        
        Stop
       
        .Quit
    End With

End Sub
```

---

**Regex:**

The regex pattern matches 3 groups in the url and then substitutes the second group, the current page number, with the new page number:

[image]

Comment: QHarr as always thanks for your help. I like your first method, however I am struggling to implement it with my exsisting navigation code due to my limited VBA. Please could you explain a bit more where and how I implement your first method. Thanks

Comment: Can you provide enough code to reproduce your issue? Hard code the url rather than from worksheet.

Comment: please see update to my question, code is there

Comment: This is now resolved, I have added some of QHarr answer to my code and it has resolved the issue, I can now navigate the pages fine

Comment: Please to hear it